# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i try to solve this problem for days but without results can you pls help me? 
here is all problem:

> Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sn\classes\DB.php:12 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sn\classes\DB.php(12): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sn\classes\Post.php(24): DB::query('INSERT INTO pos...', Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sn\profile.php(54): Post::createImgPost('', '1', '1') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\dashboard\sn\classes\DB.php on line 12

here is Post.php file:

```
<?php

class Post {
        public static function createPost($postbody, $loggedInUserId, $profileUserId) {

                if (strlen($postbody) > 160 || (strlen($postbody) < 1)) {
                        die('Incorrect lenght!');
                }

                $topics = self::getTopics($postbody);

                if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) {
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (:id, :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, \'\', :topics)', array(':id'=>0, ':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId, ':topics'=>$topics));
                } else {
                        die('Incorrect user!');
                }
        }

        public static function createImgPost($postbody, $loggedInUserId, $profileUserId) {
                if (strlen($postbody) > 160) {
                        die('Incorrect length!');
                }
                $topics = self::getTopics($postbody);
                if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) {
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (\'\', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, \'\', \'\')', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId, ':topics'=>$topics));
                        $postid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM posts WHERE user_id=:userid ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT 1;', array(':userid'=>$loggedInUserId))[0]['id'];
                        return $postid;
                } else {
                  die('Incorrect user!');
                }
          }

        public static function likePost($postId, $likerId) {
                if (!DB::query('SELECT user_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid and user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId))) {
                        DB::query('UPDATE posts SET likes=likes+1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId));
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO post_likes VALUES(:id, :postid, :userid)', array(':id'=>0, ':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId));
                } else {
                        DB::query('UPDATE posts SET likes=likes-1 WHERE id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$postId));
                        DB::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$postId, ':userid'=>$likerId));
                }
        }

        public static function link_add($text) {

                        $text = explode(" ", $text);
                        $newstring = "";

                        foreach ($text as $word) {
                              if (substr($word, 0, 1) == "@") {
                                      $newstring .= "<a href='profile.php?username=".substr($word, 1)."'>".htmlspecialchars($word)."</a>";
                              } else if (substr($word, 0, 1) == "#") {
                                      $newstring .= "<a href='topics.php?topic=".substr($word, 1)."'>".htmlspecialchars($word)."</a>";
                              } else {
                                      $newstring .= htmlspecialchars($word)." ";
                              }
                        }

                        return $newstring;
        }
        public static function getTopics($text) {

                        $text = explode(" ", $text);
                        $topics = "";

                        foreach ($text as $word) {
                              if (substr($word, 0, 1) == "#") {
                                      $topics .= substr($word, 1).",";
                              }
                        }

                        return $topics;
        }

        public static function displayPosts($userid, $username, $loggedInUserId) {
                        $dbposts = DB::query('SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id=:userid ORDER BY id DESC', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                        $posts = "";
                        foreach($dbposts as $p) {

                                if (!DB::query('SELECT post_id FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$p['id'], ':userid'=>$loggedInUserId))) {

                                        $posts .= "<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".self::link_add($p['body'])."
                                        <form action='profile.php?username=$username&postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                              <input type='submit' name='like' value='Like'>
                                              <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                        </form>
                                        <hr /></br />
                                        ";
                                } else {
                                        $posts .= "<img src='".$p['postimg']."'>".self::link_add($p['body'])."
                                        <form action='profile.php?username=$username&postid=".$p['id']."' method='post'>
                                              <input type='submit' name='unlike' value='Unlike'>
                                              <span>".$p['likes']." likes</span>
                                        </form>
                                        <hr /></br />
                                        ";
                                }
                        }
                        return $posts;
        }
   }

   ?>
```

and here is profile.php file:

```
<?php
include('./classes/DB.php');
include('./classes/Login.php');
include('./classes/Post.php');
include('./classes/Image.php');
$username = "";
$verified = False;
$isFollowing = False;
if (isset($_GET['username'])) {
          if (DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))) {
                  $username = DB::query('SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['username'];
                  $userid = DB::query('SELECT id FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['id'];
                  $verified = DB::query('SELECT verified FROM users WHERE username=:username', array(':username'=>$_GET['username']))[0]['verified'];
                  $followerid = Login::isLoggedIn();
                  if (isset($_POST['follow'])) {
                          if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                  if (!DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                                          if ($followerid == 6) {
                                                  DB::query('UPDATE users SET verified=1 WHERE id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                                          }
                                          DB::query('INSERT INTO followers VALUES (:id, :userid, :followerid)', array(':id'=>0, ':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                          } else {
                                            echo 'Already following!';
                                          }
                                  $isFollowing = True;
                          }
                  }
                  if (isset($_POST['unfollow'])) {
                          if ($userid != $followerid) {
                                  if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                                          if ($followerid == 6) {
                                                  DB::query('UPDATE users SET verified=0 WHERE id=:userid', array(':userid'=>$userid));
                                          }
                                          DB::query('DELETE FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid));
                                  }
                          $isFollowing = False;
                          }
                  }
                  if (DB::query('SELECT follower_id FROM followers WHERE user_id=:userid AND follower_id=:followerid', array(':userid'=>$userid, ':followerid'=>$followerid))) {
                          //echo 'Already following!';
                          $isFollowing = True;
                  }
                  if (isset($_POST['deletepost'])) {
                          if (DB::query('SELECT id FROM posts WHERE id=:postid AND user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid'], ':userid'=>$followerid))) {
                                  DB::query('DELETE FROM posts WHERE id=:postid and user_id=:userid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid'], ':userid'=>$followerid));
                                  DB::query('DELETE FROM post_likes WHERE post_id=:postid', array(':postid'=>$_GET['postid']));
                                  echo 'Post deleted!';
                          }
                  }
                  if (isset($_POST['post'])) {
                          if ($_FILES['postimg']['size'] == 0) {
                                  Post::createPost($_POST['postbody'], Login::isLoggedIn(), $userid);
                          } else {
                                  $postid = Post::createImgPost($_POST['postbody'], Login::isLoggedIn(), $userid);
                                  Image::uploadImage('postimg', "UPDATE posts SET postimg=:postimg WHERE id=:postid", array(':postid'=>$postid));
                          }
                  }
                  if (isset($_GET['postid']) && !isset($_POST['deletepost'])) {
                          Post::likePost($_GET['postid'], $followerid);
                  }
                  $posts = Post::displayPosts($userid, $username, $followerid);
    } else {
            die('User not found!');
    }
  }
  ?>
    <h1><?php echo $username; ?>'s Profile<?php if ($verified) { echo  - 
    Verified';` } ?></h1>
    <form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" 
    method="post">
    <?php
    if ($userid != $followerid) {
            if ($isFollowing) {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="unfollow" 
       value="Unfollow">';
            } else {
                    echo '<input type="submit" name="follow" value="Follow">';
            }
    }
    ?>
</form>

<form action="profile.php?username=<?php echo $username; ?>" method="post" 
enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <textarea name="postbody" rows="8" cols="80"></textarea>
    <br />Upload an image:
    <input type="file" name="postimg">
    <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
 </form>

 <div class="posts">
    <?php echo $posts; ?>
 </div>
```

almost every function works fine only here is some problem DB should be configured right too

probably there is problem with this query but idk where:

```
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (\'\', :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, \'\', \'\')', array(':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId, ':topics'=>$topics));
```

thank you for your time and energy

Comment: There is no placeholder for $topics

Comment: $postImg = "";
                $topics = self::getTopics($postbody);
                if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) {
                        DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (:id, :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, :postimg, :topics)', array(':id'=>0,':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId, ':postimg'=>$postImg,':topics'=>$topics));


thank you for your answer and you were right but that wasnt problem i didnt know how to set values for " \'\' " because i tried lot of things but nothing worked but finally i solved it i feel perfect :DDD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $postImg = ""; 
    $topics = self::getTopics($postbody); 
    if ($loggedInUserId == $profileUserId) { 
       DB::query('INSERT INTO posts VALUES (:id, :postbody, NOW(), :userid, 0, :postimg, :topics)', array(':id'=>0,':postbody'=>$postbody, ':userid'=>$profileUserId, ':postimg'=>$postImg,':topics'=>$topics));
```

thank you for your answer and you were right but that wasnt problem i didnt know how to set values for " \'\' " because i tried lot of things but nothing worked but finally i solved it i had to set values and create new variable... 
I feel perfect :DDD